# fixing `mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object` in babeljs 6

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

When using classes, firefox keeps warning me about:

> mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create

Is there a way to get rid of this error by having babel not setting the prototype?

I think previously this wasn't showing up when I used `protoToAssign` (now `babel-plugin-transform-proto-to-assign`) was due to firefox ignoring `setPrototypeOf`.

Comment: are you extending Object?

Comment: @JonahWilliams no, babel's code has `subClass.__proto__ = superClass` when inheriting classes.

Comment: This is just Firefox being overly aggressive. There is nothing wrong with what Babel does, you can just ignore this.

Comment: `setPrototypeOf` should in theory trigger the same warning [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). Definitely ignore it - there are many other performance hits when transpiling ES6 -> ES5, it's just the nature of it

Comment: Ok well if it's hard to avoid for now I'll just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, Babel will only mutate the `[[prototype]]` of an object if you are inheriting from a builtin class. Don't do that if you want to run your code in an ES5 environment.